# yq command to remove unnecessary fields

Tags: yaml, yq

Given a yaml file, I am looking for a yq command that will output a more "clean" list with only the relevant key "name" and its value.

for example, an output of the following yaml:

```
services:
  - name: svc1
    location: asia
    timezone: india
  - name: svc2
    location: europe
    timezone: uk
    cities:
      - london
  - name: svc3
    location: usa
    timezone: east
    cities:
      - new-york
      - brooklyn
```

Should be:

```
services:
  - name: svc1
  - name: svc2
  - name: svc3
```

Answer (score 0):

[Which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` are you using? In both, you can use the `pick` function to reduce an object to given keys, but their syntax is slightly different:

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (Tested with version 4.35.1):

```bash
yq '.services |= map(pick(["name"]))'
```

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (Tested with version 3.2.3):

```bash
yq -y '.services |= map(pick(.name))'
```

Output:

```yaml
services:
  - name: svc1
  - name: svc2
  - name: svc3
```